# Appending a div and article tag using jQuery or AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So this the code, and I want to append the `<article>` tag with data from the database to display a username and post, but then the next entry should be in the next line.

```
<div id ="test">
  <article id="main">
    <p><div id ="post"><?php //echo $row ['POST']; ?></p></div> 
     <p><?php $p= $row['POST']; ?></p>
     <a href="http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~khanna2g/public_html1/hashtagresult.php?hs=<?php echo $row['HASHTAG']; ?>">
     <?php
     $hh=$row['HASHTAG'];
     if(strlen($hh)>14){
       echo "#".$hh;
     }
     else{
       echo "";
     }
     ?>
     </a>
     <?php 
     $sqlw = "select * from A4_Comment WHERE POST ='$p'";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlw);
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {?>
     <article class = "comment">
     <?php
       echo $row['EMAIL']." :- ";
       echo $row ['Comment'];
     ?>
     <br/><br/>
     </article>
     <?php }?>
  </article>
</div>
```

This is the whole jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(d,6000);

         });
          function d(){
            $.ajax({
            url: 'homeajax.php',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data[0].pt);

                var post=document.getElementById("post");
                var main=document.getElementById("main");
                var test=document.getElementById("test2");

               var i=0;
               for(i=data.length-1;i>0;i--){

                    var r=document.createTextNode(data[i].pt);
                    main.appendChild(r);
                       //test.appendChild(main);

                   }
                               }
            });
          }
```

I am only showing posts because it was messy, but it does not show the next post in another line or in another `<article>` tag.

Comment: What is `data` in you jquery and where do you define it?

Comment: Its for database to use info from database

Comment: But I am actually looking for append functionality

Comment: ..and what is `main` - where is it defined? Is this a jQuery Object?

Comment: `<article id="main">` - I think this is main

Comment: Yeah thats the articld

Comment: maybe thats why but now I logged out everything and cannot check it

Comment: change `...length-1;i>0;..` ro `..length-1;i>=0;..`

Comment: The main thing i am concerned with is that the css i have declared for article tag should also apply for that data